# How to remove duplicate commits in a rebase-fashion

Tags: git

I am contributing to a repository that only has a master branch. Locally, I work on the master branch. When things from other people get commited there, I rebase locally. However, when I send in cherrypicked commits, they're run through an automatic system that leaves the patch content intact, but modifies the commit ID.

Therefore, when I then pull from the remote, I have an identical commit (under a different commit ID) clash with my local commit. What would be the best way to deal with this situation?

Comment: Note that if two commits have to different hashes (or ids as you call them) then the commits are not identical. You probably mean that the textual changes in the two commits are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not really a *best* way.  However, if the commit-as-patch in the copied (cherry-picked) commit matches the commit-as-patch in the original commit—which is true for many cherry-picked commits, but not all—then `git cherry` or `git rev-list --cherry-mark` can find these.  In fact, `git rebase` automatically does this.

#### Cherry-mark

To use `git rev-list --cherry-mark` you need to use the three-dot symmetric-difference notation, e.g.:

```
git rev-list --cherry-mark --left-right A...B
```

Since `A...B` means *find all commits reachable from `A` but not `B`, and vice versa*, we take a graph that forks at some point:

```
...--o--*--1--2--3   <-- A
         \
          4--5--6   <-- B
```

and we get commit series `1-2-3` reachable from `A` while `3-4-5` are reachable from `B`.  (Commit `*` and all earlier ones are reachable from both.)  Using `git log` or `git rev-list` with the three-dot notation selects those six commits.  Adding `--left-right` to `git rev-list` marks which *side* each commit hash comes from: if `<`, the commit is reachable from `A`; if `>`, the commit is reachable from `B`:

```
$ git rev-list --left-right A...B
<3...
<2...
<1...
>6...
>5...
>4...
```

for instance (assuming commit `1` has a hash ID starting with `1`, and so on).

But now suppose commit `3` is a cherry-pick of commit `4`, so that, in some sense, commit three *equals* commit 4.  Then adding `--cherry-mark` makes Git show an `=` sign in front of commits `3` and `4`.

Because this is quite useful, particularly for `git rebase`, `git rev-list` actually has the ability to *omit* such commits.  If we were to somehow tell `git rev-list` to:

- print only the right-side commits (`>` ones) in `A...B`; and
- at the same time, *omit* right-side commits that would be marked `=`

we would get the list of commits on the `B` side that should still be cherry-picked into the `A` side.  And in fact, this is what `--cherry` is designed for:

> `--cherry`
>
> A synonym for `--right-only --cherry-mark --no-merges`; useful to
>     limit the output to the commits on our side and mark those that
>     have been applied to the other side of a forked history with `git log --cherry upstream...mybranch`, similar to `git cherry upstream mybranch`.

(The rebase code uses, or used, `git rev-list` with `sed` to eliminate `=` commits, rather than using the `--cherry` option, but by this point the idea should be clear.)

#### Equality is determined by `git patch-id`

If you need something fancier than `--cherry-mark --left-right`, you can construct it yourself using the `git patch-id` command.  This reads standard input, which can be generated by running `git show`, and produces a hash ID that represents the stripped-down diff against the commit's parent(s).

Note that `git patch-id` even handles combined diffs, although copying a merge is difficult or even impossible in general.